# How can create https server using synapse in lazarus

Tags: lazarus, apache-synapse, fpc

I am trying to create https server in lazarus using synapse but I am failing. I want to mys server receive data from other https clients.
I am sending requests with my browser using https://localhost:1500 and mys server is receiving signals. But when I try to read sent data I receive nothing. When I tested simple http server all worked fine. But now in case of https it is not working. I am using ubuntu 15.04 as my OS

s := ASocket.RecvString(timeout);  //returns noething

My sample code:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

uses
  blcksock, sockets, Synautil, ssl_openssl, ssl_openssl_lib;

procedure AttendConnection(ASocket: TTCPBlockSocket);
var
  timeout: integer;
  s: string;
  method, uri, protocol: string;
  OutputDataString: string;
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  timeout := 1000;

  WriteLn('Received headers+document from browser:');

  //read request line
  s := ASocket.RecvString(timeout);
  WriteLn(s);
  method := fetch(s, ' ');
  uri := fetch(s, ' ');
  protocol := fetch(s, ' ');

  //read request headers
  repeat
    s := ASocket.RecvString(Timeout);
    WriteLn(s);
  until s = '';

  // Now write the document to the output stream

  if uri = '/' then
  begin
    // Write the output document to the stream
    OutputDataString :=
      '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"'
      + ' "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">' + CRLF
      + '<html><h1>Teste</h1></html>' + CRLF;

    // Write the headers back to the client
    ASocket.SendString('HTTP/1.0 200' + CRLF);
    ASocket.SendString('Content-type: Text/Html' + CRLF);
    ASocket.SendString('Content-length: ' + IntTostr(Length(OutputDataString)) + CRLF);
    ASocket.SendString('Connection: close' + CRLF);
    ASocket.SendString('Date: ' + Rfc822DateTime(now) + CRLF);
    ASocket.SendString('Server: Servidor do Felipe usando Synapse' + CRLF);
    ASocket.SendString('' + CRLF);

  //  if ASocket.lasterror <> 0 then HandleError;

    // Write the document back to the browser
    ASocket.SendString(OutputDataString);
  end
  else
    ASocket.SendString('HTTP/1.0 404' + CRLF);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ListenerSocket, ConnectionSocket: TTCPBlockSocket;
begin
  ListenerSocket := TTCPBlockSocket.Create;
  ConnectionSocket := TTCPBlockSocket.Create;

  ListenerSocket.CreateSocket;
  ListenerSocket.SSL.CertificateFile := '/home/imants/projects/apps/medieval/bin/40669199_localhost_8080.cert';
  ListenerSocket.SSL.PrivateKeyFile := '/home/imants/projects/apps/medieval/bin/40669199_localhost_8080.key';
  ListenerSocket.SSLDoConnect;
  ListenerSocket.setLinger(true,10);
  ListenerSocket.bind('localhost','1500');
  ListenerSocket.listen;

  repeat
    if ListenerSocket.canread(1000) then
    begin
      ConnectionSocket.Socket := ListenerSocket.accept;
      WriteLn('Attending Connection. Error code (0=Success): ', ConnectionSocket.lasterror);
      AttendConnection(ConnectionSocket);
      ConnectionSocket.CloseSocket;
    end;
  until false;

  ListenerSocket.Free;
  ConnectionSocket.Free;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Did you follow (or find) the instructions at http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/public:howto:httpsserver ?

Comment: No I found that example else where I will try to check HTTP Server Demo (which is I guess comes with synapse) and will try to change it accordingly.

Comment: unfortunately http server example witch comes with synapse is windows specifics because it uses winsock unit witch Lazarus do not support at least in Linux

Comment: As far as I can remember you can just substitute all winsock occurrences with synsock and it should work in Lazarus on Linux. (I could be wrong but try it)

Comment: Although I would advise using the latest svn version of synapse, the stable version 40 includes the httpsserv (https server) example. Try changing the winsock in synsock and removing any windows-clause. If that doesn't work you might want to try adjusting this example: https://www.mail-archive.com/synalist-public@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02225.html

Comment: Thanks that actually work. I created https server with synapse. Maybe you want to put it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sources, that I know of, with an example for a HTTP(s) server in Synapse.

The first example is in the [Synapse stable package (release 40)](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download). Although I would recommend you use the [SVN version](http://sourceforge.net/p/synalist/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/) (you can use the [Download Snapshot](http://sourceforge.net/p/synalist/code/HEAD/tarball) button on that page) you can still use the examples in the "release 40 package".

The example in `synapse40\source\demo\httpsserv` should be usable as HTTPS-server. If it's not you could take the httpserv (HTTP) example and change it as [shown here](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public:howto:httpsserver). (But I think the httpsserv is just the same with those modifications)

If you're on Linux (Lazarus) you'll need to change every occurrence of `winsock` to `synsock` and remove any `windows`-clause.

Another example can be [found here](https://www.mail-archive.com/synalist-public@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02225.html). ([Direct download of SynHttp.zip](http://semi.gurroa.cz/AltUtil/Source/SynHttp.zip)) As far as I could see it also has HTTPS-server functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you want to use Synapse, but you may want to take a look at Indy. I have been developing server/client apps with indy for some years and I like it. It's working fine with windows and linux (32bit, 64bit, arm...) and has some nice features. You could use the TIdHTTPServer component. Moreover get an IOHandlerSSLOpenSSL. The event OnCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo) is the most important one. It allows access to the Request (like A ARequestInfo.Document) and to your HTTP response (AResponseInfo).

Comment: I used indy and it worked grate. But it has some bad issues with Lazarus like my automated build server cannot compile it 100% because of some bugs in Lazarus or they're package. When compiling it throws cannot find IdStreamVCL :(. So I now try to use some other methods. But if I will not find something then yes Indy it is.

Comment: Installing Indy for Lazarus is a mess, but you don't need to :) You could just copy the indy folder into your project folder. In Lazarus press Shift + Ctrl + F11 and select Compiler Options -> Paths. Add your Indy source folder (Indy\source) to other unit files and your done :) Just add your needed units and create the components at runtime.

Comment: Your advice helped me to sort out problems with indy. It is not the best solution which I would wanted bet it is better than that it was. But as this did not answer my original question I will not accept this as answer.